# localization in ios swift. how can i change application language at run time

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization, ios9

i am creating app in ios swift. now i want to make app in dual language so from editor menu i just export and import for localization. its create two file for me.[image]

now i want to put two button on first page of my app. and when user press button 1 i want to load english language. and if user press button 2 i want to load turkish language. so how can i do this in swift?

Comment: Can the user change the language later in the app or just at start ?

Comment: just at start@MichaëlAzevedo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `NSLocalizedString` method to localize your App, load the localizable strings according to the language selected and use it from your code.

**Loading the data from the bundle :**

```
// Exemple with english language
if let path = NSBundle(forClass:object_getClass(self)).URLForResource("Localizable", withExtension: "strings", subdirectory: nil, localization: "en")?.path {
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)     {
        // Keep a reference to this dictionary
        dicoLocalisation = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
}
```

**Replacing NSLocalizedString :**

```
func localizedStringForKey(key:String) -> String { 
    // First we check if the dictionary exists       
    if let dico = dicoLocalisation {

        if let localizedString = dico[key] as? String {
            // If the localization exists, return it
            return localizedString
        }  else {
            // Returns the key if no String was found
            return key
        }
    } else {
        // If not, we can use the NSLocalizedString function
        return NSLocalizedString(key, comment: key)
    }
}
```

If you want to handle this quickly, I've made a custom localisator class available on [Github](https://github.com/micazeve/iOS-CustomLocalisator), which allow you to switch language from anywhere in the app and even save if for further launches of the app. The implementation is pretty much the same as what I've explained.

Comment: while adding language like SetLanguage("Turkish_tr") its throw error in this line  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kNotificationLanguageChanged, object: nil)

Comment: Hi, i was looking for the error you got. Did you reproduce it ? I'm glad to help otherwise :)

Comment: actually it was my fault i called function at wrong place but i solved that now its working pretty well

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm always ready to fix some bugs in my projects according to user experience.

Comment: Changing the localized dictionary will not not solve the problem of RTL (Right To Left) language. I am looking for a solution that not only will show the strings in the new language but also switch the screen from LTR to RTL. Any idea? I saw some posts but none worked even after restarting the app

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this. This leads to a very confusing user experience; people expect their apps to run in the system language they choose.

You'll also run into problems when it comes to UI and strings that you do not control, like system view controllers (e.g. sharing files) and formatters for dates, numbers, quantities, etc.

If every application had a language switcher by default, it would be a very cumbersome experience to go and select it for every app. This is why the localisation API is structured the way it is; if you use the system language fallback, then everything will work the way it should.

Comment: The apps are mostly made to run with device language, but I already faced a case where a client wanted to switch language according to a remote server. I created then this localisation class.

Comment: Once again this is not recommended and will still be confusing. It's very much worth the effort to have your client reconsider not having a confusing experience for their users.

Comment: actually i am new to app development and in ios swift. so what is the other way to set language by region@wakachamo

Comment: Settings -> General -> Language & Region

Comment: @wakachamo your approach is, in my view, paternalistic. If a user wants the app to be in another language than the device language, you should assume that he/she knows why.

Comment: i really disagree with this answer. 
your answer is just something like lazy to do the work.
and this is not the answer for this question