# Reload the app programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I created localization for my storyboard (English, Arabic) and I did the function that changes (switch) the App. language (local) it's working perfect if I restart (relaunch) the app manually and my Views flip Right-Let if Arabic and Left-Right if English as well, but how can I change the storyboard local without restarting my app manually?.

I used this function to change the language

```
 func setLocale(langCode:String){

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject([langCode], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [localization in ios swift. how can i change application language at run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425788/localization-in-ios-swift-how-can-i-change-application-language-at-run-time)

Comment: I am using NSLocalizedString and storyboard localization, so I don't want to change the labels only, I have to reload the bundle because it should flip Right-Left for Arabic or Left-Right for English. I saw many apps did it. As soon as you select the new language it re-launch the app with the selected localized.

Comment: Please check this gist: https://gist.github.com/afshin-hoseini/a46f431fbe6bb20fde8e8ed675e81018

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta Yes, I did

Comment: Can you tell me how>Please post your answer here

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do. However this code is in Obj-C.

Create a category class for NSBundle like this:

```
#import "NSBundle+ForceLocalization.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>


static const char _bundle=0;
@interface BundleEx : NSBundle
@end

@implementation BundleEx

-(NSString*)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    NSBundle* bundle=objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_bundle);
    return bundle ? [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName] : [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
}
@end

@implementation NSBundle (ForceLocalization)

+(void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
                  {
                      object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[BundleEx class]);
                  });
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &_bundle, language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

After this, simply call:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: langCode, nil]
                                                  forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[NSBundle setLanguage: langCode];
```

You need to reload the UI for the current screen again. If you go on to another controller, you'll see the updated language.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and I didn't work with Obj-C before.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for same answer today and I could't find it, but I used this code

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
```

to reload the main view controller and it did some how restart the app, although there was some problems with connected views to storyboard that I removed them from superView...